# iteration with i in an if statement in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a while loop, inside it is a for loop, and inside that is an if statement to check if a condition is met. I'm getting an error when I try to iterate through the xs data set vectors but I have no idea how to make this compatible, and I thought you could use "i" as an index in arrays. What am I doing wrong? This is using numpy.

```
Your code raises an exception. The following is the traceback of the failure:

   File "<ipython-input-5-25a0c5c7dd52>", line 32, in classifier
    if ys[i,:] * np.dot(w.T, xs[i,:]) <= 0: 


def classifier(xs,ys):
    xs : n input vectors of d dimensions (nxd)
    ys : n labels (-1 or +1)

    m = 0
    
    while m < 100:  
        m = 0
        for i in xs:
            if ys[i] * np.dot(w.T, xs[i]) <= 0: # <--- error
            # do stuff
            m = m + 1
        if m == 0:
            break
```

Comment: Hi, what is the error?What is w? Post [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Where does `ys` come from?

Comment: This is a basic Python iteration issue.  Read some more Python basics.  With `for i in xs:` `i` is an element of `xs`, NOT an index.  You can't use it with `xs[i]`.  That doesn't make sense, even with a Python list.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question. xs and ys are parameters of the function

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Mentioning what errors you encounters, and see on the console and elsewhere will surely help those who will answer your question.

Comment: @hpaulj that is not necessarily true. You are right about the iteratio but `x = [0,1,2,3]

for i in x:
    print(x[i])` works perfectly fine

Comment: @hpaulj Why is that? I want to multiply a scaler with the the dot product of a column in xs and w.T ( another vector with matching dimensions to the column from xs). Why is it impossible?

Comment: @ShivamJha the error wasn't really that helpful but I posted it

Answer (score 0):

Make a list and iterate on it:

```
In [3]: x = ['a','b','c']
In [4]: for i in x:
   ...:     print(i)
   ...: 
   ...: 
a
b
c
```

Note that it shows elements of the list, not indices (0,1,...).

Same for an array:

```
In [5]: x = np.array(x)
In [6]: x
Out[6]: array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
In [7]: for i in x:
   ...:     print(i)
   ...: 
   ...: 
a
b
c
```

It would be wrong to try `x[i]`.

Or if `x` is a 2d array, I get rows:

```
In [8]: x = np.array([[1,10,11],[12,0,3]])
In [9]: for i in x:
   ...:     print(i)
   ...: 
[ 1 10 11]
[12  0  3]
```

To get indices, I have to iterate on a `range`, or list like `[0,1,2]`:

```
In [10]: for i in range(3):
    ...:     print(i, x[:,i])
    ...: 
    ...: 
0 [ 1 12]
1 [10  0]
2 [11  3]
```